# Remove elements from webpage in query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code (Bootstrap and Jquery):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal fade" id="modalSubscriptionForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header text-center">
          <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Subscribe</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                         </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body mx-3">
          <div class="md-form mb-5">
            <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
            <input type="text" id="form3" class="form-control validate val1" name="val1">
            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form3">Title</label>
          </div>
          <div class="md-form mb-4">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
            <input type="email" id="form2" class="form-control validate val2" name="val2">
            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form2">Desc</label>
          </div>
          <div class="md-form mb-4">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form2">
                               Coordinates click: 
                               <div class="coorX"></div>
                               x 
                               <div class="coorY"></div>
                            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button class="btn btn-indigo saveBtn">Send <i class="fas fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scalize imgpo">
    <img src="img/jacket.png" alt="" class="target ">
    <div class="item-point" data-top="130" data-left="300" id="point1">
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle tooltips" title="<h1><b>Another</b> <em>one</em> here too 1</h1>" data-placement="top" data-html="true" rel="tooltip"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-point" data-top="180" data-left="462" id="point2">
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle tooltips" title="<h1><b>Another</b> <em>one</em> here too 2</h1>" data-placement="top" data-html="true" rel="tooltip"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-point" data-top="380" data-left="215" id="point3">
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle tooltips" title="<h1><b>Another</b> <em>one</em> here too 3</h1>" data-placement="top" data-html="true" rel="tooltip"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-point" data-left="357" data-top="458" id="point4">
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle tooltips" title="<h1><b>xxxxx</b> <em>one</em> here too 4</h1>" data-placement="top" data-html="true" rel="tooltip"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4 formAdd" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSubscriptionForm" style="display:none"></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.imgpo').click(function(e) {
      var posX = $(this).position().left,
        posY = $(this).position().top;
      $('.coorX').html((e.pageX - posX - 10));
      $('.coorY').html((e.pageY - posY - 10));
      $(".tooltip").tooltip("hide");
      $('.formAdd').click();
    });

    $('.saveBtn').click(function(e) {
      var val1 = $(".val1").val();
      var val2 = $(".val2").val();

      var values = {
        'val1': val1,
        'val2': val2
      };


      alert('Save');


      $.ajax({
        url: "save.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        success: function(response) {
          alert('Save');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('Error');
        }


      });

    });


    $('.scalize').scalize({
      styleSelector: 'circle',
      animationPopoverIn: 'flipInY',
      animationPopoverOut: 'flipOutY',
      animationSelector: 'pulse2'
    });
    /*
                  $('.tooltips').tooltip({
             html: true,
                    trigger: 'click',
                    placement: 'top'
             })
                  */
    const $tooltip = $('.tooltips');
    $tooltip.tooltip({
      html: true,
      trigger: 'click',
      placement: 'top',
    });
    $tooltip.on('show.bs.tooltip', () => {
      $('.tooltip').not(this).remove();
    });
    $tooltip.on('click', (ev) => {
      ev.stopPropagation();
    })


  });
</script>
<div class="itemsBox">
  <form name="saveForm" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="obiect1">Obiect 1
      <div class="removeMe" id="1">X</div>
    </div>
    <div class="obiect2">Obiect 2
      <div class="removeMe" id="2">X</div>
    </div>
    <div class="obiect3">Obiect 3
      <div class="removeMe" id="3">X</div>
    </div>
    <div class="obiect4">Obiect 4
      <div class="removeMe" id="4">X</div>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

prview: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/component/index2.html

In this webpage I have:

```
1. points on image points (id = point1 to point4),
2. objects (obiect1 to obiect4).
```

I have too removeMe with ID 1-4.

I would like that after clicking a div with the class removeMe, for example, ID = 2 - the page has been removed:

```
1. obiect2
2. point2
```

Could I ask you to write the code?
I would like to delete entire blocks of obiect2 and point2 together with what is inside (html content)

How to do it?

Comment: *"Could I ask you to write the code?"* StackOverflow is **not** a code-writing service. Given that it looks like you've shown an attempt (granted I haven't combed through it), we're generally happy to help out and point out what you may have done wrong, but in the future just be sure you mention the *specific* issue you're having. **EDIT:** Correction, I see nothing in your code that attempts to do what you're asking us to write for you.

Comment: ^ As such, your code lacks a clear problem statement (Why can't you accomplish this on your own? What's holding you back?), it doesn't provide a reproducible error (there is no error because there is no attempt), and is *off-topic*. Please take a look at the [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) resource to see what you can do to edit and improve your question. Thanks traekdjf.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the number from the id of `.removeMe` and use this in the selectors for point and abject to find the corresponding elements.

```js
$('.removeMe').on('click', function() {
  var number = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#point' + number).remove();
  $('.obiect' + number).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="obiect1">Obiect 1
  <div class="removeMe" id="1">X</div>
</div>
<div class="obiect2">Obiect 2
  <div class="removeMe" id="2">X</div>
</div>
<div class="obiect3">Obiect 3
  <div class="removeMe" id="3">X</div>
</div>
<div class="obiect4">Obiect 4
  <div class="removeMe" id="4">X</div>
</div>

<div class="scalize imgpo">
  <img src="img/jacket.png" alt="" class="target ">
  <div class="item-point" data-top="130" data-left="300" id="point1">
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="toggle tooltips" title="<h1><b>Another</b> <em>one</em> here too 1</h1>" data-placement="top" data-html="true" rel="tooltip">point1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-point" data-top="180" data-left="462" id="point2">
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="toggle tooltips" title="<h1><b>Another</b> <em>one</em> here too 2</h1>" data-placement="top" data-html="true" rel="tooltip">point2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-point" data-top="380" data-left="215" id="point3">
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="toggle tooltips" title="<h1><b>Another</b> <em>one</em> here too 3</h1>" data-placement="top" data-html="true" rel="tooltip">point3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-point" data-left="357" data-top="458" id="point4">
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="toggle tooltips" title="<h1><b>xxxxx</b> <em>one</em> here too 4</h1>" data-placement="top" data-html="true" rel="tooltip">point4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't like downvoting without providing a reason, so I'll share my thoughts. Originally I was going to mention that you hadn't pointed out what OP did wrong, or why his attempt wasn't working. Which then made me realize that OP didn't actually even attempt to solve this on his own, and literally said *"Could I ask you to write the code?"*. I'm downvoting for the reasons given [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions) (stating that answers to clearly bad questions should be downvoted along with the question itself).

Comment: @TylerRoper, I think you are over reacting. He might not have formulated and formatted his question in a correct way, but it seems he only had problem tackling a small issue. If he would have asked: "how can i remove elements based on the id of a clicked element?" it would have been fine. And it's basically what he did but in a bit of an inappropriate way.

Comment: Asking *"how can i remove elements based on the id of a clicked element?"*, without showing any attempt nor any research, is a horrible question. Not to mention it's likely a duplicate of 100 other questions. It isn't related to phrasing, it's the idea that you've just written code for someone who didn't even make an attempt at doing it themselves. I feel that this answer encourages users to come to SO before even trying, under the impression we'll just write their code for them. I don't think it's an overreaction - I just think I owed you a decent explanation.